# Elasticsearch 5.1.1cannot bind local ip address

Tags: elasticsearch, ip-address

I am trying to map local ip address in ES yml file using below configuration
network.bind_host: 0
and getting below error

Exception in thread "main" ed to resolve publish address]; nested:

```
IllegalArgumentException[No up-and-running global-scope (public) addresses found, got [name:lo (Software Loopback Interface 1), name:net0 (WAN Miniport (L2TP)), name:net1 (WAN Miniport (SSTP)), name:net2 (WAN Miniport (IKEv2)), name:net3 (WAN Miniport (PPTP)), name:ppp0 (WAN Miniport (PPPOE)), name:eth0 (WAN Miniport (IP)), name:eth1 (WAN Miniport (IPv6)), name:eth2 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)), name:eth3 (Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter), name:ppp1 (RAS Async Adapter), name:eth4 (vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter), name:net4 (Microsoft ISATAP Adapter), name:net5 (Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface), name:eth5 (vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000), name:eth6 (vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000), name:eth7 (vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000), name:eth8 (WAN Miniport (IP)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000), name:eth9 (WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000), name:eth10 (WAN Miniport (IPv6)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000), name:eth11 (WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000), name:eth12 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000), name:eth13 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)]];
Likely root cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No up-and-running global-scope (public) addresses found, got [name:lo (Software Loopback Interface 1), name:net0 (WAN Miniport (L2TP)), name:net1 (WAN Miniport (SSTP)), name:net2 (WAN Miniport (IKEv2)), name:net3 (WAN Miniport (PPTP)), name:ppp0 (WAN Miniport (PPPOE)), name:eth0 (WAN Miniport (IP)), name:eth1 (WAN Miniport (IPv6)), name:eth2 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)), name:eth3 (Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter), name:ppp1 (RAS Async Adapter), name:eth4 (vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter), name:net4 (Microsoft ISATAP Adapter), name:net5 (Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface), name:eth5 (vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000), name:eth6 (vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000), name:eth7 (vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter-WFP 802.3 MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000), name:eth8 (WAN Miniport (IP)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000), name:eth9 (WAN Miniport (IP)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000), name:eth10 (WAN Miniport (IPv6)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000), name:eth11 (WAN Miniport (IPv6)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000), name:eth12 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-WFP Native MAC Layer LightWeight Filter-0000), name:eth13 (WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)-QoS Packet Scheduler-0000)]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkUtils.getGlobalAddresses(NetworkUtils.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.resolveInternal(NetworkService.java:252)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.resolveInetAddresses(NetworkService.java:220)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.network.NetworkService.resolvePublishHostAddresses(NetworkService.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.createBoundTransportAddress(TcpTransport.java:665)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindServer(TcpTransport.java:604)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:182)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:188)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:577)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:234)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:308)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:121)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:82)
Refer to the log for complete error details.
```

Using Elasticsearch 5.1.1

Answer (score 3):

What if you try changing the `network.host` flag from the `elasticsearch.yml` :

```
network.host:0.0.0.0
```

Where [network.bind_host](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings) defaults to the value of  *network.host*. If it's the **local ip address** that you're trying to map, shouldn't it be `127.0.0.1`!

Comment: i'm trying to connect using local ip (10.X.X.X:9200), so it doesn't work for me with 0.0.0.0 but crash is not happening with complete address instead of 0. I am changing the yml directly and restarting the service

Comment: @user3784070 so did you try changing **network.host: 10.X.X.X** and **http.port: 9200**? If the *port* is 9200, it's not necessary to have the **http.port** assigned to it, since ES will be running on 9200 by default. So does crash not happening, mean that it's working properly now?

Comment: crash is not happening if i use network.host : 127.0.0.1 but if use 10.X.X.X or 0.0.0.0 then ES is crashing. We are using custom port and specifying it in yml file.

Comment: Are you running your ES instance from `10.X.X.X `?

Comment: yes it is running from 10.X.X.X, basically it is single node configuration but i want to able to ping ES with ip address also not just with localhost. I'm trying from the same node where ES instance is running with ip address. We require this because if in customer machine if we have 10.X.X.X mapped to localhosts in their hosts file

Comment: It should be up and running when you point the `ip address`. What's the custom port you're using? Make sure it's not within 9200-9400!

Comment: we are using 32570 port

Comment: if i use network.publish_host: 10.X.X.X, ES is crashing again, ES is not crashing if i use network.host : 127.0.0.1 only

Comment: What's the output of this: `netstat -an |grep 32570`? Is it listening to your `ip address`? And is that the only error which you're getting?

Comment: I tried netstat -ano | findstr "LIST and doesn't show listening to my ip address.....BTW netstat command you provided is not working it says not recognized

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options if you just want it on 127.0.0.1. For example you can use one of the following:

```
network.host: [ "127.0.0.1" ]
network.host: [ "_local_" ]
network.host: [ "_lo_" ]
```

Optionally you can specify some of these more explicitly if it's just the IPv4 version that you want to specify:

```
network.host: [ "_local:ipv4_" ]
network.host: [ "_lo:ipv4_" ]
```

It's been my experience that the `"_local_"` works most of the time. The `"_lo_"` version I've run into when running VM's on a VMWare ESX environment. It was unclear why this was required, but the `"_lo_"` version worked fine.

There are other special vales such as `"_site_"` and `"_global_"` as well.

#### References

- [Special values for network.host](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#network-interface-values)